# What is an alternative in AWS for sending message from SNS to SQS FIFO?

Tags: amazon-web-services, message-queue, amazon-sqs, amazon-sns

I have this situation where I am using Amazon SNS + SQS in order to handle domain events.

Basically on domain event I publish a message to SNS and two SQS queues are subscribed to SNS. Since i noticed SQS supports FIFO, but SNS doesn't support FIFO, I am trying to find a resolution on how to simultaneously deliver message A to multiple SQS FIFO queues?

What I had so far

- Publish Message A to SNS
- Distribute Message A to SQS 1 and SQS 2

All I can think of now is

- Publish message A to SQS A
- Use code to pull message A from SQS and publish it to SQS 1 and SQS 2

Not really an atomic process I was looking for...

Is there an alternative to this approach?

Comment: What exactly are you wanting to accomplish? Is something not working for you? Amazon SNS sends messages immediately, but messages might be delayed if they require re-sends. Is there a problem with your current configuration that isn't meeting your requirements?

Comment: Short version is AWS doesnt allow SQS (FIFO) to subscribe to SNS

Comment: Ah! I get it now. Is there a specific reason why you are using FIFO queues? Amazon SQS queues are FIFO-ish, but it is not guaranteed. Does your use-case specifically require FIFO to be enforced?

Comment: Unfortunately yes, because i need to recreate domain in other systems. In order to recreate it i need to use fifo. Or there is another way to pull messages from sns based on message group (for example doman id). I know meesage groups exist in sqs fifo, but not in sns

Comment: SNS now supports FIFO https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/aws/introducing-amazon-sns-fifo-first-in-first-out-pub-sub-messaging/

Answer (score 1):

Today, we launched Amazon SNS FIFO topics, which can fan out messages to multiple Amazon SQS FIFO queues!

https://aws.amazon.com/about-aws/whats-new/2020/10/amazon-sns-introduces-fifo-topics-with-strict-ordering-and-deduplication-of-messages/

Answer (score 0):

You can think about using the `AWS Kinesis Data stream`. One feature of it is an `ordering`.

From faq: https://aws.amazon.com/kinesis/data-streams/faqs/

> *When should I use Amazon Kinesis Data Streams, and when should I use Amazon SQS?*

> Ordering of records. For example, you want to transfer log data from the application host to the processing/archival host while maintaining the order of log statements.

You can process events from Kinesis to SQSs.

Answer (score 0):

If your goal is to have a message be pushed to two Amazon SQS FIFO queues, I'd recommend:

- Have **Amazon SNS** trigger an AWS Lambda function
- The **Lambda function** can send the same message to both **Amazon SQS queues**

It is effectively doing the **fan-out via Lambda** rather than SNS.

The Lambda function might also be able to extract a [Message Group ID](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSSimpleQueueService/latest/SQSDeveloperGuide/using-messagegroupid-property.html) that it can provide with the SQS message, which will enable parallel processing of messages while maintaining FIFO within the message group. For example, all messages coming from a particular source will be FIFO, but can be processed in parallel with messages from other sources. It's a *very* powerful capability that would not be available just by having Amazon SNS forward the message.